# Numpy - How to remove trailing N*8 zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I have 1d array, I need to remove all trailing blocks of 8 zeros.

```
[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
->
[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0]
```

`a.shape[0] % 8 == 0` always, so no worries about that.

Is there a better way to do it?

```py
import numpy as np
P = 8
arr1 = np.random.randint(2,size=np.random.randint(5,10) * P)
arr2 = np.random.randint(1,size=np.random.randint(5,10) * P)
arr = np.concatenate((arr1, arr2))

indexes = []
arr = np.flip(arr).reshape(arr.shape[0] // P, P)

for i, f in enumerate(arr):
    if (f == 0).all():
        indexes.append(i)
    else:
        break

arr = np.delete(arr, indexes, axis=0)
arr = np.flip(arr.reshape(arr.shape[0] * P))
```

Comment: If they'll always be at the end just slice them off `a = a[:-8]`

Comment: I don't know how many there will be.

Comment: What do you mean by "trailing N % 8 == 0 zeros"? That doesn't sound like a number of zeros you want to remove.

Comment: I want to remove 8 or 24 or 8000 or N*8 zeros.

Comment: why not a=a[:-N*8] ?

Comment: N is unknown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without allocating more space by using views and [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to get the last nonzero element:

```
index = arr.size - np.argmax(arr[::-1])
```

Rounding up to the nearest multiple of eight is easy:

```
index = np.ceil(index / 8) * 8
```

Now chop off the rest:

```
arr = arr[:index]
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
arr = arr[:(arr.size - np.argmax(arr[::-1])) / 8) * 8]
```

This version is `O(n)` in time and `O(1)` in space because it reuses the same buffers for everything (including the output).

This has the additional advantage that it will work correctly even if there are no trailing zeros. Using `argmax` does rely on all the elements being the same though. If that is not the case, you will need to compute a mask first, e.g. with `arr.astype(bool)`.

If you want to use your original approach, you could vectorize that too, although there will be a bit more overhead:

```
view = arr.reshape(-1, 8)
mask = view.any(axis = 1)
index = view.shape[0] - np.argmax(mask[::-1])
arr = arr[:index * 8]
```

Comment: I would caution that if `arr` is an empty list, or if there are no non-zero numbers, this will throw an error. Make sure you check that before running your admittedly very nice one-liner.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth. Updated. There is a much better solution apparently.

Answer (score 0):

There is a numpy function that does almost what you want `np.trim_zeros`. We can use that:

```
import numpy as np

def trim_mod(a, m=8):
    t = np.trim_zeros(a, 'b')
    return a[:len(a)-(len(a)-len(t))//m*m]

def test(a, t, m=8):
    assert (len(a) - len(t)) % m == 0
    assert len(t) < m or np.any(t[-m:])
    assert not np.any(a[len(t):])

for _ in range(1000):
    a = (np.random.random(np.random.randint(10, 100000))<0.002).astype(int)
    m = np.random.randint(4, 20)
    t = trim_mod(a, m)
    test(a, t, m)

print("Looks correct")
```

Prints:

```
Looks correct
```

It seems to scale linearly in the number of trailing zeros:

[image]

But feels rather slow in absolute terms (units are ms per trial), so maybe `np.trim_zeros` is just a python loop.

Code for  the picture:

```
from timeit import timeit

A = (np.random.random(1000000)<0.02).astype(int)
m = 8
T = []
for last in range(1, 1000, 9):
    A[-last:] = 0
    A[-last] = 1
    T.append(timeit(lambda: trim_mod(A, m), number=100)*10)

import pylab
pylab.plot(range(1, 1000, 9), T)
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

A low level approach :

```
import numba
@numba.njit
def trim8(a):
    n=a.size-1
    while n>=0 and a[n]==0 : n-=1
    c= (n//8+1)*8
    return a[:c]
```

Some tests :

```
In [194]: A[-1]=1  # best case

In [196]: %timeit trim_mod(A,8)
5.7 µs ± 323 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [197]: %timeit trim8(A)
714 ns ± 33.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [198]: %timeit A[:(A.size - np.argmax(A[::-1]) // 8) * 8]
4.83 ms ± 479 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [202]: A[:]=0 #worst case

In [203]: %timeit trim_mod(A,8)
2.5 s ± 49.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [204]: %timeit trim8(A)
1.14 ms ± 71.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [205]: %timeit A[:(A.size - np.argmax(A[::-1]) // 8) * 8]
5.5 ms ± 950 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

It has a short circuit mechanism like  `trim_zeros`, but is much faster.